# How can I insert a login JFrame into a test in Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, jframe

When I call the JFrame from another class to test, the JFrame works, but when I insert it into my Selenium test, the JFrame and the browser open so quickly that there's no time to input anything and the test appears like passed.

Sample of the elements that I mention:

```
@Test
public void Run() throws InterruptedException{
     Keys.loginFrame(); //This method is static in another class named 'Keys'
     ...
     
}
```

Is there any way to say to Selenium the following?:

Execute first ONLY `Keys.loginFrame();`, then wait till the JFrame is closed. Finally execute the rest of the test code.

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

1. remake your `loginFrame()` method to return `JFrame` object
2. add this method:

---

```
public static void startFrameThread(JFrame frame) {
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            while (frame.isVisible()) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } 
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        }
    };
    thread.start();
    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent arg0) {
            frame.setVisible(false);
        }
    });
    try {
        thread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
}
```

---

3. apply new usage:

---

```
JFrame loginFrame = Keys.loginFrame();
loginFrame.setVisible(true); // if not setting visible in loginFrame() method
startFrameThread(loginFrame);
```